Bayes' formula for distriibutions
In my statistics course, we have discussed Bayes' theorem for distributions:
$$
p(\theta | y)=\frac{p(y|\theta)p(\theta)}{\int p(y|\theta)p(\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta}
$$
Where $p(\theta)$ is the prior distribution for the parameter $\theta$, $p(y|\theta)$ is the likelihood of obtaining our data given the parameter, and $p(\theta|y)$ is the posterior distribution.
I am not entirely sure if the likelihood is a probability mass function or a probability density function. My intuition is that all of these are probability density functions. But there are some examples in class where this wouldn't make sense.
We have covered cases using a beta-prior and binomial likelihood. If the likelihood were a density function, then the steps for calculating the posterior would be:
$$
p(y | \theta) = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \theta^y (1-\theta)^{n-k} \delta(y-k)
$$
$$
p(\theta) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha,\beta)}\theta^{\alpha-1} (1-\theta)^{\beta-1}
$$
$$
\int_0^1 p(\theta)p(y|\theta) \mathrm{d}\theta = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{B(\alpha + k,\beta+n-k)}{B(\alpha,\beta)} \delta(y-k)
$$
$$
p(\theta | y) = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \theta^{\alpha+k-1}(1-\theta)^{\beta+n-k+1}\delta(y-k)}{ \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} B(\alpha+k,\beta+n-k)\delta(y-k)}
$$
However this result conflicts with the result my professor gave that $\theta|y\sim \mathrm{Beta}(\alpha + y,\beta + n - y)$ unless there's a way to cancel the sum and delta functions. If the probability mass function for the binomial distribution were used, then the issue would resolve itself.
Does this mean that $p(y|\theta)$ is always a probability mass function, or are there conditions in which it is a probability density function? If it can be either one, how do you know which to use?
I believe a similar issue arrises when using a Gamma prior and a Poisson likelihood. Most of the work I will be doing will involve MCMC to find the posterior distribution, but I would like to better understand the theoretical aspects.

Whether the  likelihood is a mass function or a density function will depend on the type of data. It will be a mass function when the data is discrete and a density function when the data is continuous.
For example, imagine we want to know the distribution of peoples heights $y$ which follow a normal distribution (with some priors $\theta$ for the mean and varaince). Then the distribution $p(y|\theta)$ is just a normal distribution, i.e. a density function.

Is this the same for the likelihood function as well?

yeh this is how things work for the likelihood function @sodium-hydroxide
